# How to resolve this FB firebase auth credential error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

The error I gotten was invalid credentials[ remote site 5XX from facebook.com for USER_INFO ] , do I need to initialize the credential and token.
I an using firebase realtime DB and Facebook auth.
I have ensure that the app id and app secret is correct, the Facebook developer web app is also in live mode.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script>
var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
  };
firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.analytics()
var database = firebase.database();
var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

function fblogin() {
firebase
  .auth()
  .signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then((result) => {
    var user = result.user;
    var credential = result.credential;
    var accessToken = credential.accessToken;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
alert(errorCode)
    var errorMessage = error.message;
alert(errorMessage)
    var email = error.email;
    var credential = error.credential;
  });
}
```

Comment: Please share a screenshot of the error.

Comment: It basically says  auth/invalid_credentials and [ Remote site 5XX from facebook.com for USER_INFO ]. Other than the setup is there anything wrong with the js code for facebook auth.

Comment: Have you correctly configured the facebook credentials in Firebase console?

Comment: Yes. I have enable it and set the app is and app secret properly

Comment: Have you checked [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63238335/13130697) ?

Comment: I have seen it. The solution did not work